# Read and Eval can't resolve symbols in local scope

Tags: clojure

I was trying something like

```
(let [x 1] (load-string "(str x)"))
```

But it gave me an error saying:

```
CompilerException java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve symbol: x in this context, compiling:(null:1:1)
```

I am not able to understand why the `load-string` function is not able to resolve the `x` symbol in the `let` block.

I am able to execute it if I define a symbol `x` in the global scope, but that is not what I want.

Comment: It makes no sense to use eval like that. Why should it know about your lexical closures? Perhaps you should use `apply` instead?

Comment: I don't know that it makes "no sense". It is not supported by Clojure's evaluation model, but other languages have chosen to support this in their `eval`.